# why is jquery .ajax giving 400 (Bad Request) in a simple GET request

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, bad-request

I'm having a problem getting a jquery .ajax call to

Here's the javascript code that invokes the get.

```
    let Url = CoreControllerUrl + 'GenericGet?transactionId=GetRaAdvisees&arg1=' + advisorId + '&arg2=' + xvm.termId() + '&arg3=none';
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: Url, type: "GET", dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) { getAdviseesSuccess(result); },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert("System Error!  Unable to retrieve your advisees list for the specified term");
            }
        }
    );
```

The problem is that I'm getting the alert (line 6) even though I believe everything is correct.
The browser's console shows that I'm getting "AjaxErrorOccurred 400 (Bad Request)" error

Putting a javascript break in the browser shows that the url property is getting set to
/Ellucian.Web.Student/M32/Core/GenericGet?transactionId=GetRaAdvisees&arg1=0278540&arg2=2021S16&arg3=none
(browser and server are both running on my local development system)

Putting a breakpoint in the server's action method shows that it never gets to that point.
Just for grins, here's that method

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GenericGet(string transactionId, string arg1, string arg2, string arg3)
{
    try
    {
        var result = ServiceClient.XGenericGet(transactionId, arg1, arg2, arg3);
        return Json(new StandardJsonResult(result), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Error(e, e.Message);
        return Json(new StandardJsonResult(statuscode: HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, message: e.Message), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds quick and dirty, but why not just remove line 6 (the error line if I counted right) and just below the request include a line that checks to see if there was an error and then output the alert? I am fairly certain there is an event listener that you can tie to the ajax request that is set off when a request is made and received... And can you clarify by what you mean by "Putting a breakpoint in the server's action method shows that it never gets to that point...", like does it fire the function or never touch it at all?

Comment: Note it's a lot easier to pass an object to $.ajax `data` than manually add the query params in the url string

Comment: So I had to do a little reading, but something to note is that http response 400 is a response sent back from the server saying that the request was not properly configured. Just a note: `You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.` as per docs.

Comment: @ShanerM13 I do use the "type" property.  Note that I set it to "GET".   And I assume that "Bad Request" does mean "request not properly configured".   The question is "in what way is it not properly configured?"

Comment: @charlietfl - I changed it to use the data property as follows:    url: CoreController+"GenericGet", data: { transactionId: "GetRaAdvisees", arg1: advisorId, arg2: xvm.termId(), arg3: "none"},.    And it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how/why,  but when I moved the ajax call inside a $(document).ready(...
then it started working.
Thank you  @ShanerM13, @charlietfl

Comment: Oh my gosh... I didn't realize it wasn't inside a $(document.read()); Glad its working now. I could see the answer as to why it behaved this way being very technical. My hunch is that some jQuery resource needed to send the request wasn't loaded 100% (because it wasn't inside a doc.read()) and thus threw an error.